# How to write the correct syntax for backgroundImage in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to define a 's backgroundImage in a map() function but I can't understand what the correct syntax is to add one:

I have a variable named *value* that stores a file's name and I want to insert *uploads/* in my backgroundImage because it's the folde where I want the backgroundImage to fetch the images.

I've tried:

```
<div className="image-show" key={index} style={{backgroundImage: URL({'uploads/' + value})}}>
```

But it returns the following error:

[image: Error]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try out :

```
style={{backgroundImage: "url(uploads/" + value + ")" }}

//OR

style={{backgroundImage: `url(uploads/${value})` }}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, tried the second option and it worked fine!

Comment: @AntónioLima,Glad to know, it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace:
`{'uploads/' + value}`

with the following:

```
{ `uploads/${value}`}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div className="image-show" key={index} style={{backgroundImage: "url(uploads/" + value + ")" }}>
```

The general syntax is :

```
backgroundImage: "url(" + background_image + ")"   

--- where background_image is a string(path of  your image)
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS style fields that you pass in components must have value in number or string.

Instead of `style={ {backgroundImage: URL({uploads/12345})} }`

React expects `style={{backgroundImage: "url(uploads/12345)" }}`

I hope that helps